# Is there any software to view hidden (invisible) online friends in Google Talk?

Tags: internet, chat, google-talk

Is it possible to view the hidden (invisible) online friends in Google Talk?

I heard that it is possible in Linux through the GtalX client software, but I don't know whether that information is correct?

Any other observations on this?

Comment: Really Sorry Kronos! me accepted the great answers ..Won't repeat this again from my side.

Comment: Why the moderator flag? Moderators do not ensure questions get answered. Please do not flag a question because it didn't receive a response.

Comment: then why that flag is active in my account/question ?

Comment: It's not active, question was flagged, for some reason. It'll go fade in few days. @Renj

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of posts which say this is possible [using this method](http://devilsworkshop.org/google-added-invisible-mode-to-gmail-chat-google-talk/):

> - Set the chat as off the record with target user. This can be done only when the other user is online.
> - Now try sending chat to that user when he is invisible or offline.
> - If he is invisible, then he will receive chat.
> - But if he Is offline, then you will receive error “ did not receive your chat”.

Caveats include:

- I haven't tested this
- You need to have had a chat with the user without having closed the chat window.

Personally, I don't see why this is needed. If the user's offline, send an e-mail.